# How to Create mutiple Tables on word with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, dynamic, ms-word, office-interop

```
 Dim Linha3 = WordDoc.Paragraphs.Add
            Dim Tabela = WordDoc.Tables.Add(Linha3.Range, 7, 5)
            Tabela.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            Tabela.Range.Font.Size = 8
            Tabela.Columns(2).Width = 50
            Tabela.Columns(3).Width = 150
            Tabela.Columns(4).Width = 80
            Tabela.Columns(5).Width = 80
            Tabela.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
            Tabela.Cell(1, 4).Merge(Tabela.Cell(1, 5))
```

My question is. I wanna do this on a loop, cuz I gotta create mutiple tables. The problem is, when the loop occours it gives me a error saying that like Columns(2) was alredy resized, and kind double it... So I was thinking I gotta create like "Tabela2" but how can I create a dynamic variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing on add more tables was. On my code, here:

```
Dim Tabela = WordDoc.Tables.Add(Linha3.Range, 7, 5)
```

The "WordDoc.Paragraphs.Add" wasnt the same I was using on the WordDoc. I was using "Linha" for the rest of the document instead of Linha3. Idk why it make diference, but that is what was giving me error.
So I just change it to "Linha", and it worked fine, with some custom editing to the Text of some cells.

```
Dim WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
Dim Linha = WordDoc.Paragraphs.Add
```

The answer is just dont add another WordDoc.Paragraphs, And u should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objApp = New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document

    'For New Page = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
    'For New section without a corresponding page break = Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakContinuous
    Dim objPageBreak As Object = Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakContinuous

    objApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objApp.Visible = True
    objDoc = objApp.Documents.Add

    For i = 1 To 3
        CreateTableInWordDocument(objDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, objDoc, objApp)
        objDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range.InsertBreak(objPageBreak)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub CreateTableInWordDocument(objRange As Word.Range, objDoc As Word.Document, objApp As Word.Application)
    Dim objTable As Word.Table

    objTable = objRange.Tables.Add(objRange, 7, 5)
    objTable.Borders.Enable = True
    objTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleDouble
    objTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle

    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    For r = 1 To 7
        For c = 1 To 5
            objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "Row" & r & " Column" & c
        Next
    Next

    objTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
    objTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Italic = True

    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

You must add one Button1 control in Windows desktop App and use this code - in loop For i=1 To 3 - here 3 is the count of tables to add in a Word document.